# I am adding a button but it doesnt work

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am added a button to another page but its not working, and I'm a newbie
I went to Stsdt>layout>fragment_main.xml and I wrote:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/abusgo"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="About us" />
```

Then I went to Stsdt>src>com.examplhe.sfsdf and I created PageOne.java and I wrote

```
setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
```

Then I went to Sfsdf>com.examplhe.sfsdf>MainActivity and I added:

```
Button abusto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.abusgo);
```

and

```
abusto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
```

Then I went to Manifest and I added at the end this:

```
<activity android:name=".PageOne" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"> <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.PAGEONE" /> <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> </intent-filter> </activity>
```

During running eclipse, it works fine but in the mobile, there is something wrong and I don't see anything from it
Help :)

Comment: Show us some more code. And what exactly is the reason that you set the layout in PageOne, but add the listener in MainActivity? Also, what does not work? "Does not work" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: can you show your LogCat please

Comment: I couldnt paste anything, it can be seen here http://sarozain.angelfire.com/

Answer (score 0):

When you call `findViewById`, it will look in the layout file for that particular activity (i.e., if you call it from your activity, it will look in activity_main.xml).

In your case, the button is actually in the fragment's layout file, so you would need to move the call into the fragment's class. Assuming that your fragment code is within PageOne.java, then you should look for the button in PageOne.java. (Also, if it's a fragment, you don't need to add anything to the manifest-- only if it's an activity)

Comment: I changed the activity_main.xml to fragment_main.xml and in it tools:context="com.examplhe.sfsdf.PageOne" but its not working, I install it on the mobile but it gave me no run!